# How to build a form for for an event that doesn't have a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to build an admin form that allows User.admin's to send out an invitation welcome email.

I have an admin controller where this would likely live. In the form all I need to do is enter an email. What's the right way to build this form given I don't have a invitation welcome controller or model?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean without a persisted model? Or no model at all?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a controller that accepts the form's input. You cannot simply connect together a form to the mailer and have it sent out. You need an intermediary step in there.

You should create a controller, or at least an action in a controller, which takes the request along with the email and passes it on to a mailer:

```
def send_invitation_email
  UserMailer.invitation(params[:email]).deliver
end
```